# Returning the larger of two numbers if at least one if positive and returning 0 otherwise

Tags: python

I have a function trunc_max(x,y) which accepts as input two numbers x,y and returns the larger of the two numbers if one is positive and returns 0 otherwise. My code is below.

```
    def trunc_max(x,y):
     if x>0 or y>0:
      if x>y:
       return x
      if y>x:
        return y
      else:
        return 0
```

I think my code makes sense because it says if x or y is positive and if x is greater than y return x then it says if y is greater than x return y else return 0 which means it should work but there probably is something wrong in my if statements. Any ideas?

Comment: `max([0, x, y])`

Comment: The "else" should be in indentation with the very first "if".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with identation. Last "else" must refer to the first "if". The code should be like this:

```
def trunc_max(x,y):
    if x>0 or y>0:
        if x>y:
            return x
        if y>x:
            return y
    else:
        return 0
```

Also as Barmar commented, you must add a statement for the case that x==y.
Your full code must be:

```
def trunc_max(x,y):
        if x>0 or y>0:
            if x>y:
                return x
            if y>x:
                return y
            if x==y:
                return x (#or y, whatever you want to return)
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: You don't return anything if `x == y`

Answer (score 0):

You don't return `0` when both numbers are not positive. You return `0` when `x == y`, since neither of the comparisons succeed.

After you determine that at least one is positive, you can just use the built-in `max()` function.

```
def trunc_max(x, y):
    if x > 0 or y > 0:
        return max(x, y)
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def trunc_max(x, y):
    return max(x,y,0)

print(trunc_max(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a **Indentation Issue** If notice in last else statement is nested with the previous if but it should one tab back
so the correct code is

```
def trunc_max(x,y):
if x>0 or y>0:
    if x>y:
        return x
    if y>x:
        return y
else:
    return 0
```

if the input is -1,-6 ,the first if is not satisfied so it returns zero from the else statement.

A shorter form of this code is

```
def trunc_max(x, y):
if x > 0 or y > 0:
    return max(x, y)
return 0
```

or

```
def trunc_max(x, y):
    return max(x,y,0)
```